# Is there any faster way to bring the loaded data from the Ignite Cache?

Tags: caching, ignite

I loaded my data in types of  and  by using Apache Ignite Cache. 
 type of data is approximately 2GB size and it is in form of byte[5604*300,000] and I get the cache values from the Ignite Client using "Iterator it = cache.localEntries(CachePeekMode.PRIMARY).iterator()"
The problem is that it takes too much time to transform the loaded data into byte[] type.

Is there any faster way to bring the loaded data from the cache?
and currenetly loacalEntries' returning data type is Iterator. Is there any way to return different data type?

Comment: How much time does it take now, and how fast does it need to be? Have you discovered a hardware bottleneck?

Comment: Another question - why do you need to convert to byte[] while reading? Can you clarify what you mean by that?